# Python multiprocessing Queues reliability, Queue vs SimpleQueue vs JoinableQueue

Tags: python, process, multiprocessing

Straight from the Python [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html):

> class multiprocessing.Queue([maxsize])
>
> ...
>
> qsize() 
>   Return the approximate size of the queue. Because of multithreading/multiprocessing semantics, this number is not reliable.
>
> empty()
>   Return True if the queue is empty, False otherwise. Because of multithreading/multiprocessing semantics, this is not reliable.

And I've empirically found this to be quite true for `Queue`, especially for `empty()`.

In my code I have a bunch of processes (each a child of the same master process) and each having the following in their `run` method:

```
while self.active:
    if(self.exclusive_queue.empty() and self.exclusive_queue.qsize() == 0):
        try:
            self.exclusive_queue.put(self.general_queue.get(timeout=self.queue_timeout))
        except Queue.Empty as empty_queue:
            continue
    else:
        task = self.exclusive_queue.get()
        self.compute(task)
```

Basically, the process waits on the `general_queue` for work, but first checks its `exclusive_queue`. The master process can put tasks in either the general or in the exclusive queue of a process. Now, in the `if(self.exclusive_queue.empty() and self.exclusive_queue.qsize() == 0)`, I first used a `self.exclusive_queue.empty()` which resulted in quite a weird behaviour (`qsize()` of 30+ and `empty() = True`).

So where I'm heading with this is - for `multiprocessing.queues.SimpleQueue` in the docs is written:

> empty()
>   Return True if the queue is empty, False otherwise.

with no mention of reliability at all. Is SimpleQueue.empty() reliable?

And second is `multiprocessing.JoinableQueue` reliable or "more" reliable than `Queue` because of the `task_done()` mechanism?

Can such an approach be considered correct or perhaps an approach with callbacks (via a shared pipe endpoint between the children) be more appropriate?

Comment: In my case `SimpleQueue` could store only a too small number of elements [roughtly 360 `(int, str, int)-tuples)`]. For that reason I decided to use a `STOP` element (as mentioned in `Midnighter`s answer) with Queue. For Queue I did not hit a size limitation even after 100 000 elements of the same structure.

Answer (score 7):

Not a direct answer but I've started to rely more and more on iterating the input queue with a guarding condition. There is an example in the documentation of the multiprocessing module:

```
def worker(input, output):
    for func, args in iter(input.get, 'STOP'):
        result = calculate(func, args)
        output.put(result)
```

So when your input to the queue is complete, you simply `put` as many `STOP` strings, or whatever guard you choose, to the queue as you have started processes .

Comment: Yes, I pretty much use the same approach in my server. If `compute` gets a `None` it changes `active` to `False`. However, as you can see in my case I have two queues to wait on - the "exclusive" and "general" queue with the idea being "if exclusive is empty get from general", however, because I want to be able to stop processes even if there are entries in the general queue I put the `None`s in the exclusive ones.

Comment: Processes can die without cleaning up properly so this technique worries me slightly.

Comment: If a worker process dies, then it doesn't need to be stopped anyway. If there are other resources to clean up that is not handled by this approach here, true, but I would argue that that's not its purpose anyway.